# Aligning drawable to centre of button

Tags: android, button

I have a button but I am not able to align the drawable in it to the centre. Here is my code -

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:background="#ff2fa73a"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:drawableStart="@mipmap/yes_go"
        android:layout_marginTop="156dp" />
```

[image]

Comment: Post your entire xml (need to know parent layout)

Comment: I suggest you may apply ImageButton instead of Button when you do not contain text inside it

Comment: It is just in a relative layout

Comment: @Mark023 have you tried using : android:centerInParent="true" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just use an `ImageButton`:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_marginTop="156dp"
    android:src="@mipmap/yes_go"
    android:background="#ff2fa73a" />
```

(also, you should use the *drawable* folders for your image, *mipmap* is for launcher icons specifically)

Answer (score 0):

I have used `drawable-left` and then adjust the padding.

You can use like that.

```
    <Button
    android:layout_below="@+id/imgSave"
    android:id="@+id/btnSearch"
    android:layout_width="170dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_camera"
    android:drawablePadding="0dp"
    android:paddingLeft="40dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="12dp"
    android:paddingBottom="12dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"/>
```

[link](http://devstune.com/tutorial/lesson/8)